# C++ Cross platform methods of obtaining more detailed control of console input

Tags: c++, input, keyboard

I am working on an experimental project to print things like message boxes and windows within a console. (In ascii)

Terminals usually do not allow the programmer a fine degree of control over input handling.

For example, I have a loop which draws message boxes etc in ascii and then does the following to obtain input:

```
string input;
cin >> input;

ui.ProcessInput(input); // ui is a class which stores messageboxes/optionboxes to be printed to screen in ascii
```

This is fine for objects such as "optionboxes" (my own naming convention) where the user is asked to enter "1" "2" or "3" to respond to a question.

However for a simple "messagebox" hitting return does not work (on Linux) because if the console sees an end of line char without any other characters before it, that line is ignored.

Hence one has to enter some nonsense text for `ui.ProcessInput()` to be called.

Is there any way I can get characters / keyboard codes from the terminal/console window in a cross platform, C++ standard way, which I can then manually process?

Comment: Unless you're scanning keyboard strokes directly (which is absolutely OS dependent), you cannot. Input for `cin` will be seen only after ENTER.

Comment: Does ncurses work on Windows?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No input is seen after enter if no input is given before enter. However pressing CTRL-D does work.

Comment: @immibis Can't use external libraries unfortunatly

Comment: @user3728501 Then I don't think there is any cross platform, C++ standard way.

Comment: @immibis I was afraid of this...

Comment: @immibis Can I not do something funky with file pointers or memory addresses and read input from files or something?

Comment: @user3728501 How is reading input from a file going to help you with reading input from the console and displaying output to the console?

Comment: @immibis My guess would be unix uses some sort of file for transfering IO from keyboard and mouse?

Comment: @user3728501 `stdin` and `stdout`, which wrap FDs 0 and 1? Special input and output is usually done with "escape codes" (sequences of characters that aren't printable). But that's on Unix/Linux. On Windows you'd use the console API functions, which do things directly without mucking around pretending the console is a file. (E.g. to set the cursor position you just call `SetConsoleCursorPosition`)

Comment: @immibis Guess not very cross platform?

Comment: @user3728501 It's semi-cross-platform in that you only have to handle two platforms.